# Getting layer name from getFeaturesAtPixel in OL4

Tags: openlayers

I'm trying to build a popup that only shows feature info from certain layers. How do I get layer name?

I've tried this:

```
const features = this.map.getFeaturesAtPixel(evt.pixel, {
  layerFilter: ((layerCandidate: layer.Layer) => {
    if (layerCandidate.get('name') === 'my layer') {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  )});`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var feature = Map.olMap.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function (feature, layer) {
                    options.layer = layer;
                    options.features = feature;
                    options.modify = self.currentInteraction;
                    options.sender = self;
                    callback(options);
                });
```

In these codes, you can get all layer properties with this command

```
options.layer.getProperties()
```

`title`, `opacity`, `visible` and other details about layer.